# Найти средства выразительности

Tags: стилистика

Открыв рано утром мышеловку, тетушка увидела незваную гостью. Мышь преспокойно сидела в ловушке, будто она всю жизнь там жила. Не церемонясь с нахалкой, тетушка взяла ее двумя пальцами за хвост и вышвырнула за дверь. Мышь, освобожденная из плена, быстро юркнула под крыльцо и стала обдумывать новые пути проникновения в дом. Ведь под столом остался не убранный кухаркой аппетитный кусочек сыраи бесчисленное количество крошек.

Найти языковые средства выразительности.

Подходят такие - слова с уменьшительно-ласкательным суффиксом  (тетушка), эпитет (аппетитный), олицетворения  (мышь, освобожденная из плена)? Или есть еще?

Comment: незваную-одно -Н-. Несов. вид, завис.слов нет, противопост. нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тетушка - да, слово с уменьшительно-ласкательным суффиксом, оценочная лексика.

аппетитный - эпитет

освобожденная из плена - эпитет, это же образное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом.

стала обдумывать пути проникновения в дом - олицетворение

бесчисленное количество - преувеличение-гипербола. Такое не проходили?

незваная гостья - опять-таки перифраз, но Вы его не проходили. Может, как эпитет обозначить "незваная"?